# Not able to communicate with servlet using angularjs

Tags: mysql, angularjs, servlets

I am trying to insert form data using Angularjs as frontend and servlet as backened with Mysql.I am not able to pass data from my angularjs to servlet.When i click on Save button form data is not inserted into database.
Here is my index.html

```
   <div ng-app="myApp">
   <form ng-controller="myCtrl">
   Name: <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="data.name"><br>
   Address: <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="address" ng-  model="data.address"></textarea>
   <br>
   <button ng-click="add(data)">Save</button>
   </form>
   <script>
   var app=angular.module('myApp', [])
   app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
   $scope.add = function (data) {
       $http.post('/AngularDb/RegisterServlet', data,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
       .then(
        function(response) { 
         console.log('success if post worked', response) 
        },
        function(error) { 
         console.error('error if error processing post', error);
        });
      }
    });
    </script>
    </div>
```

Here is my servlet:RegisterServlet.java

```
    @WebServlet("/RegisterServlet")
    public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // JDBC driver name and database URL
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate";
    //  Database credentials
    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "root";
    public RegisterServlet() {
    super();
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
        Connection conn=null;
        try{
            String name = request.getParameter("name");
            String address = request.getParameter("address");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            String sql = "INSERT INTO register (name, address) values ('"+name+"', '"+address+"');";
            PreparedStatement psSql = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            psSql.executeUpdate();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try{
                if(conn!=null)
                    conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException se){
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: any errors? have you checked the network traffic to se if it is an FE or BE issue?

Comment: No errors.But nothing is displayed in the console and data also not inserted into database @Jax

Comment: Did you check the request under 'network' tab in your developer console? What is the response?